# Basic question about open balls and open sets

Tags: metric-spaces

In a metric space,the union of two open sets is open,i.e, $U=(4,6)\cup (9,14)$.

1)Is this true because all the points that belong to $U$ are interior points?

But $U$ is not an open ball.

2)Is it because there is not open ball with center in $U$ that contains only interior points? 3)Could you consider the balls with center outside U to prove that not all points are interior?

Comment: 1) Yes: a set is *open* whwn all its point are interior points. And in $U$ every point can be "surrounded" by open balls.

Comment: 1. Yes, correct. A set is open iff it is a union of open balls. 2. Note that an open ball must contain its center. Balls in $\Bbb R$ are connected.

Comment: And $U$ is not an open ball because there is no way to find a "center" $a$ and a "radius" $r$ such that $B_r(a)$ contains **all** and only points of $U$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can I try to find this "center" outside the set $U$? (If $U$ is contained in a bigger set)

Comment: For metric space $X$, $B_r(a) = \{ x \in X \mid d(x,a) < r \}$. But $d(a,a)=0 < r$ for $r$ whatever. Thus : $a \in B_r(a)$ by definition, i,.e. the "center" is inside the ball. Intuitively, an open ball is a circle without circumference...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions in order:

1) Yes. You may pick any $u\in U$, and note that you can construct an $\epsilon=(1/2)\min\{|6-u|,|4-u|,|9-u|,|14-u|\}$, and then the open ball $B(u,\epsilon)$ is contained in $U$.

2) Yes. If $U=B(x,r)$ for some $x\in U$ and $r>0$, then by considering cases where $x\in (4,6)$ or $x\in (9,14)$, and using the definition of an open ball $B(x,r)=\{z\in\mathbb{R}:d(z,x)<r\}$, one can show that the points in $(4,14)\setminus(4,6)\cup (9,14)$ are in $B(x,r)$.

3) If there is a ball with centre outside of $U$, say $B(y,r')$ for some $y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus U$, then by the definition of an open ball, you can show that $B(y,r')\neq U$.